# What's wrong with SELECT DISTINCT?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know what's wrong with my code,
I use distinct but it returns to continously 2013 it should be 2013-2007.

```
$qry = "SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y') As Year FROM table";
while ($row = MySQL_fetch_array($result)) {
  $content .='<li><label for="folder1">' . date('Y', strtotime($row['Year'])) . '</label> <input type="checkbox" id="folder1" /> ';

}
```

Comment: And I don't know too - since you've not posted any data - samples of current data and desired result

Comment: Can you post a Dump of you table please.  You sure that you have other than 2013 ?

Comment: give a table with sample entries.

Comment: maybe date is prereserved in your sql server - could you please try to put it in accent graves DATE_FORMAT(\`date\`, '%Y')

Comment: yes i pretty sure i have a year other than 2013. I run it on mysql and i got a list of 2013-2007 but when i put it on a php i only got 2013 i dont know y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to be formatting the date in PHP as well as MySQL, try with just:

```
while ($row = MySQL_fetch_array($result)) {
    $content .='<li><label for="folder1">' . $row['Year'] . '</label> <input type="checkbox" id="folder1" /> ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting the date that has to be displayed and not actually changing the the value that will be used for comparison. Try using it Year(date) as a function

"Select distinct Year(date) as year from table"

Should work